# Difference between two dates from two consecutive rows in two different columns

Tags: unix, hive, hiveql, unix-timestamp, hue

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8bgK.png)I have a hive table with more than millions records. 
The input is of the following type:
Input:

```
rowid     |starttime              |endtime                  |line   |status
--- 1     2007-07-19 00:05:00    2007-07-19 00:23:00        l1     s1 
--- 2     2007-07-20 00:00:10    2007-07-20 00:22:00        l1     s2
--- 3     2007-07-19 00:00:00    2007-07-19 00:11:00        l2     s2
```

What I want to do is when 1st order the table by starttime group by line. 
Then find the difference between two consecutive rows endtime and starttime. If the difference is more than 5mins then in a new table add a new row in between with status misstime.

In input row 1 & 2 the time time difference is 1 hour 10 mins so 1st I will create row for 19th Date and complete that days with missing time and then add one more row for 20th as below.

output:

```
rowid |starttime               |endtime              |line   |status
--- 1 |2007-07-19 00:05:00     |2007-07-19 00:23:00  |l1     |s1 
--- 2 |2007-07-19 00:23:01     |2007-07-19 00:00:00  |l1     |misstime
--- 3 |2007-07-20 00:00:01     |2007-07-20 00:00:09  |l1     |misstime
--- 4 |2007-07-20 00:00:10     |2007-07-20 00:22:00  |l1     |s2
--- 3 |2007-07-19 00:00:00     |2007-07-19 00:11:00  |l2     |s2
```

Can anyone help me achieve this directly in hue - hive ? 
Unix script will also do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please share sample date and corresponding result set in proper readable formate

Comment: Sorry about the formatting. Let me try to submit this in picture file format. thanks for replying though.

Comment: Please click on the link to check the image view of the problem with formatting. Sorry about the inconvenience caused.

Answer (score 0):

The solution template is:

1. Use LAG() function to get previous line starttime or endtime.
2. For each line calculate the different between current and previous time
3. Filter rows with difference more than 5 minutes.
4. Transform the dataset into required output.

Example:

```
    insert into yourtable
    select 
    s.rowid, 
    s.starttime ,
    s.endtime,
    --calculate your status here, etc, etc
from    
    (
    select rowid starttime endtime, 
           lag(endtime) over(partition by rowid order by starttime) prev_endtime
    from yourtable ) s
    where (unix_timestamp(endtime) - unix_timestamp(prev_endtime))/60 > 5 --latency>5 min
```

Comment: I didn't check this and do not understand clearly the output requirement but hope you have caught the idea.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and keep you posted.

Comment: Please click on the link to check the image view of the problem with formatting if needed. Sorry about the inconvenience caused.

Comment: I get this error when i use your solution:ParseException line 3:1 cannot recognize input near 'select' 'material_id_extract' ',' in function specification; My actual query used:-- insert into poc_ccts.sd_test_mps
select s.material_id_extract,s.line_desc,s.starttime,s.endtime 
(select material_id_extract,line_desc, starttime, endtime, 
       lag(endtime) over(partition by line_desc order by starttime) prev_endtime
from poc_ccts.qs_mps where starttime like '2007-07-%' and material_id_Extract like '83703412') s
where (unix_timestamp(endtime) - unix_timestamp(prev_endtime))/60 > 10

Comment: 'from' was missing : corrected version is - insert into yourtable
select 
s.rowid, 
s.starttime ,
s.endtime from 
--calculate your status here, etc, etc

(
select rowid starttime endtime, 
       lag(endtime) over(partition by rowid order by starttime) prev_endtime
from yourtable ) s
where (unix_timestamp(endtime) - unix_timestamp(prev_endtime))/60 > 5 --latency>5 min

Comment: This doesnt allow me to create new rows as in desired output. Can you further help in how do I create rows in new table and then may be i will join them or union the two tables.

Comment: I'm sorry but ... Please explain better the desired output. It seems that first row is simply the same as in input? Should output contain all input rows as well and additional rows should be generated? How many additional rows do you need to create for each input row? How each column in additional rows was calculated, it is not clear about start and end times, status, if they were taken from other rows or calculated, please explain exactly how it should be. I do not also understand why the time difference as in your description is 1 hrs 10 minutes... How it was calculated?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8bgK.png : image shows the output; What I want to do is when 1st order the table by starttime group by line. Then find the difference between two consecutive rows endtime and starttime. If the difference is more than 5mins then in a new table add a new row in between with status misstime.

In input row 1 & 2 the time time difference is 1 hour 10 mins so 1st I will create row for 19th Date and complete that days with missing time and then add one more row for 20th as below;

Comment: The starttime in new row will be as per endtime of previous row + 1 second. ENdtime will be either 12 midnight if rows generated are more than 1 else endtime will be input row's endtime.

Comment: So If there are more than 1 day difference, the number of created rows for these two source rows should be NUMBER_OF_DAYS_DIFFERENCE+1 ? 0 days difference but more than 5 minutes = 1 additional row, 1 day difference - 2 additional rows (one for each day + one for the same day as first row), 2 days - three more rows - right?

Comment: Have you a date_dim table? It may be used to generate rows for missed days. The idea is to take date_dim as a base table, left join your dataset on date=your date, generate missed rows,  mark these rows with some status, store to intermediate table,  then apply to this table the logic with lag and once more  to calculate rows for missed time, filter only these rows for missed time and UNION ALL with intermediate table. I'm sorry but your requirements seems too complex for question here.

Comment: Thanks Leftjoin. logic sounds good. Can you help me write the query for this ? Can i do this without scripting ?

Comment: Seems it's possible to do using pure Hive sql. Try it yourself show your try here and someone may help to fix it.